# NSUserDefaults in Swift - implementing type safety

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, type-safety

One of the things that bugs me about Swift and Cocoa together is working with NSUserDefaults, because there is no type information and it is always necessary to cast the result of `objectForKey` to what you are expecting to get. It is unsafe and impractical. I decided to tackle this problem, making NSUserDefaults more practical in Swift-land, and hopefully learning something along the way. Here were my goals in the beginning:

1. Complete type safety: each key has one type associated with it. When setting a value, only a value of that type should be accepted and when getting a value the result should come out with the correct type
2. Global list of keys which are clear in meaning and content. The list should be easy to create, modify and extend
3. Clean syntax, using subscripts if possible. For example, this would
   be perfect:

   3.1. set:    UserDefaults[.MyKey] = value

   3.2. get:    let value = UserDefaults[.MyKey]
4. Support for classes that conform to the NSCoding protocol by
   automatically [un]archiving them
5. Support for all property list types accepted by NSUserDefaults

I started by creating this generic struct:

```
struct UDKey <T>  {
    init(_ n: String) { name = n }
    let name: String
}
```

Then I created this other struct that serves as a container for all the keys in an application:

```
struct UDKeys {}
```

This can then be extended to add keys wherever needed:

```
extension UDKeys {
    static let MyKey1 = UDKey<Int>("MyKey1")
    static let MyKey2 = UDKey<[String]>("MyKey2")
}
```

Note how each key has a type associated with it. It represents the type of the information to be saved. Also, the name property is the string that is to be used as a key for NSUserDefaults.

The keys can be listed all in one constants file, or added using extensions on a per-file basis close to where they are being used for storing data.

Then I created an "UserDefaults" class responsible for handling the getting/setting of information:

```
class UserDefaultsClass {
    let storage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    init(storage: NSUserDefaults) { self.storage = storage }
    init() {}

    // ...
}

let UserDefaults = UserDefaultsClass() // or UserDefaultsClass(storage: ...) for further customisation
```

The idea is that one instance for a particular domain is created and then every method is accessed in this way:

```
let value = UserDefaults.myMethod(...)
```

I prefer this approach to things like UserDefaults.sharedInstance.myMethod(...) (too long!) or using class methods for everything. Also, this allows interacting with various domains at the same time by using more than one UserDefaultsClass with different storage values.

So far, items 1 and 2 have been taken care of, but now the difficult part is starting: how to actually design the methods on UserDefaultsClass in order to comply with the rest.

For example, let's start with item 4. First I tried this (this code is inside UserDefaultsClass):

```
subscript<T: NSCoding>(key: UDKey<T>) -> T? {
    set { storage.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newValue), forKey: key.name) }
    get {
        if let data = storage.objectForKey(key.name) as? NSData {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? T
        } else { return nil }
    }
}
```

But then I find out that Swift doesn't allow generic subscripts!! Alright, then I guess I'll have to use functions then. There goes half of item 3...

```
func set <T: NSCoding>(key: UDKey<T>, _ value: T) {
    storage.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(value), forKey: key.name)
}
func get <T: NSCoding>(key: UDKey<T>) -> T? {
    if let data = storage.objectForKey(key.name) as? NSData {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? T
    } else { return nil }
}
```

And that works just fine:

```
extension UDKeys { static let MyKey = UDKey<NSNotification>("MyKey") }

UserDefaults.set(UDKeys.MyKey, NSNotification(name: "Hello!", object: nil))
let n = UserDefaults.get(UDKeys.MyKey)
```

Note how I can't call `UserDefaults.get(.MyKey)`. I have to use `UDKeys.MyKey`. And I can't do that because it's not yet possible to have static variables on a generic struct!!

Next, let's try number 5. Now that has been an headache and that's where I need lots of help.

Property list types are, as per the docs:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

That in Swift means `Int`, `[Int]`, `[[String:Bool]]`, `[[String:[Double]]]`, etc are all property list types. At first I thought that I could just write this and trust whoever is using this code to remember that only plist types are allowed:

```
func set <T: AnyObject>(key: UDKey<T>, _ value: T) {
    storage.setObject(value, forKey: key.name)
}
func get <T: AnyObject>(key: UDKey<T>) -> T? {
    return storage.objectForKey(key.name) as? T
}
```

But as you'll notice, while this works fine:

```
extension UDKeys { static let MyKey = UDKey<NSData>("MyKey") }

UserDefaults.set(UDKeys.MyKey, NSData())
let d = UserDefaults.get(UDKeys.MyKey)
```

This doesn't:

```
extension UDKeys { static let MyKey = UDKey<[NSData]>("MyKey") }
UserDefaults.set(UDKeys.MyKey, [NSData()])
```

And this doesn't either:

```
extension UDKeys { static let MyKey = UDKey<[Int]>("MyKey") }
UserDefaults.set(UDKeys.MyKey, [0])
```

Not even this:

```
extension UDKeys { static let MyKey = UDKey<Int>("MyKey") }
UserDefaults.set(UDKeys.MyKey, 1)
```

The problem is that they are all valid property list types yet Swift obviously interprets arrays and ints as structs, not as their Objective-C class counterparts. However:

```
func set <T: Any>(key: UDKey<T>, _ value: T)
```

won't work either, because then any value type, not just the ones that have a class cousin courtesy of Obj-C, is accepted, and `storage.setObject(value, forKey: key.name)` is no longer valid because value has to be a reference type.

If a protocol existed in Swift that accepted any reference type and any value type that can be converted to a reference type in objective-c (like `[Int]` and the other examples I mention) this problem would be solved:

```
func set <T: AnyObjectiveCObject>(key: UDKey<T>, _ value: T) {
    storage.setObject(value, forKey: key.name)
}
func get <T: AnyObjectiveCObject>(key: UDKey<T>) -> T? {
    return storage.objectForKey(key.name) as? T
}
```

`AnyObjectiveCObject` would accept any swift classes and swift arrays, dictionaries, numbers (ints, floats, bools, etc that convert to NSNumber), strings...

Unfortunately, AFAIK this doesn't exist.

**Question:**

How can I have write a generic function (or collection of overloaded generic functions) whose generic type T can be any reference type **or** any *value* type that Swift can convert to a reference type in Objective-C?

---

**Solved:** With the help of the answers I got, I arrived at what I wanted. In case anyone wants to take a look at my solution, [here](https://gist.github.com/truppelito/3e72faa4e14e432ea60d#file-userdefaults-swift) it is.

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense. User defaults are meant to be a (somewhat more comfortable) way to store command invocation parameters. It's not about saving complete objects.

Comment: @ThomasKilian On most of my projects I end up saving data structures like `[[String:[Int]]]` and custom objects like `TimerInfo`, `Person`, `Event`, things like that. The objects are not very complicated and there's no reason for using more sophisticated libraries like CoreData. I don't see why this doesn't make sense. Besides, it's a great learning opportunity.

Comment: I usually end up doing serialization for those objects which reduces it to a minimum number of strings/ints/floats. Of course YMMV. But as you don't share the user defaults I guess type safety is of less importance. I'd just create a wrapper class around it to ensure you get what you want.

Comment: This is beautiful. I was working on something similar but less elegant.

Comment: @appzYourLife Thanks! I agree: I think this can be very useful, but it has to work first!

Comment: Take a look at SwiftyUserDefaults, I should solve what you are trying to do.

[SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults/blob/master/Src/SwiftyUserDefaults.swift)

Comment: @LaurentRivard Yes, that is an interesting way of Swiftifying NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't mean to brag but ... oh who am I kidding, I [totally do](https://gist.github.com/vmanot/090f88b2a4329c1e0daa)!

```
Preferences.set([NSData()], forKey: "MyKey1")
Preferences.get("MyKey1", type: type([NSData]))
Preferences.get("MyKey1") as [NSData]?

func crunch1(value: [NSData])
{
    println("Om nom 1!")
}

crunch1(Preferences.get("MyKey1")!)

Preferences.set(NSArray(object: NSData()), forKey: "MyKey2")
Preferences.get("MyKey2", type: type(NSArray))
Preferences.get("MyKey2") as NSArray?

func crunch2(value: NSArray)
{
    println("Om nom 2!")
}

crunch2(Preferences.get("MyKey2")!)

Preferences.set([[String:[Int]]](), forKey: "MyKey3")
Preferences.get("MyKey3", type: type([[String:[Int]]]))
Preferences.get("MyKey3") as [[String:[Int]]]?

func crunch3(value: [[String:[Int]]])
{
    println("Om nom 3!")
}

crunch3(Preferences.get("MyKey3")!)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, the protocol `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` is exactly what I wanted!!

Comment: Ups, yep ... but consider that the `_` prefix suggests some caution when using it in production code.

Comment: Typically `_` is used for undocumented internal types protocols etc. This means that they might change in the future without any communication / documentation. Swift is still in huge evolution, thus this solution might be not stable in _time_. If it is not part of a private api, you can use it ... just know it. Anyway this might be mitigated by the fact that it is guaranteed that your app will have your current swift runtime in the bundle. Thus once it is distributed, it will work even after Apple's updates

Comment: @perlfly: I wrote a post detailing the new naming conventions, which can be viewed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366121/what-does-an-underscore-mean-in-swift/28366122#28366122).

Comment: Indeed here it comes at how _do not use directly_ is interpreted. Swift has changed a lot in a few months. And now that they are implementing the standard library we can figure out other changes to come. Maybe after WWDC2015 it will be more stable. I'm not saying to not absolutely use it, just evaluate costs/benefits in case they change it. Just normal considerations when you directly access third party _implementation details_.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to introduce my idea. (Sorry for my poor English in advance.)

```
let plainKey = UDKey("Message", string)
let mixedKey
    = UDKey("Mixed"
        , array(dictionary(
            string, tuple(
                array(integer),
                optional(date)))))

let ud = UserDefaults(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults())
ud.set(plainKey, "Hello")
ud.set(plainKey, 2525) // <-- compile error
ud.set(mixedKey, [ [ "(^_^;)": ([1, 2, 3], .Some(NSDate()))] ])
ud.set(mixedKey, [ [ "(^_^;)": ([1, 2, 3], .Some(NSData()))] ]) // <-- compile error
```

The only difference is that `UDKey()` now requires #2 argument, a value of `BiMap` class. I've uncoupled the work originally of `UDKey` into `BiMap` which converts a value of a type to/from a value of another type.

```
public class BiMap<A, B> {
    public func AtoB(a: A) -> B?
    public func BtoA(b: B) -> A?
}
```

Consequently, types that `set/get` can accepts are conducted by `BiMap`, and no longer limited to types `as` can automatically cast
 from/to `AnyObject` (more specifically, types `NSUserDefaults` can accepts.).

Because `BiMap` is a generic class, you can easily create subtypes of that, interchanging arbitrary two types you want.

Here is full source code. (But there are bugs yet to be fixed..)
https://gist.github.com/hisui/47f170a9e193168dc946